# How to get historical graph of processes' activity in Process Explorer (SysInternals)

Tags: windows, process, windows-7

I noticed a strange behaviour on my laptop, during the night when there are no humans around.

Sometimes fan spins up to high RPMs and it looks like the computer is processing something. It happened also that the laptop would wake up by itself a few times.

I would like to get a 24h history graph of every process that has been running and their respective resource utilisation. Is it possible to get it in ProcessExplorer? What is the best way to do it?

Comment: I disagree. if questions on how to do something in Kali are on topic here, (they are, it has a tag) then questions on how to do something in SysInternals are equally on topic.

Comment: Questions about usage of security tools are on-topic, but SysInternals is not a security tool.